# Error while compiling ipsec tools...What does PATH_IPSEC_H actually mean?

Tags: c, ipsec

Like I said in the title.  I'm trying to compile libipsec right now and am having a world of difficulty (not using the C library it was intended to be compiled on).  Many of my errors are caused from the line

`#include PATH_IPSEC_H`,but path_ipsec_h is never declared anywhere and It does not seem like a C keyword...

What does `PATH_IPSEC_H` actually mean?  Would this line be equivalent to `#include <ipsec.h>`?

If I did not provide the correct information...sorry..I'm still new to this.  Just tell me what you need to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for a file named `config.h`, it is very likely to define this symbol to the proper value for your environment. I took a quick look in a [randomly-chosen ipsec file](http://cvsweb.netbsd.org/bsdweb.cgi/src/crypto/dist/ipsec-tools/src/racoon/ipsec_doi.c?rev=1.31.6.2&content-type=text/x-cvsweb-markup&sortby=rev&only_with_tag=matt-mips64), and it starts:

```
#include "config.h"

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/param.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

#include <netinet/in.h>

#include PATH_IPSEC_H
```

This indicates either that `PATH_IPSEC_H` is defined by `config.h`, or passed in on the command line when compiling this file. The presence of the `#include "config.h"` line makes that (in my opinion, without any prior knowledge of this particular library) the most likely choice.

**Update:** also, it's very likely that this `config.h` file is created by some build-tool, i.e. it's probably not there unless you've run the proper tool to generate it, typically after analyzing your environment.

Comment: Oh that makes a lot of sense.  I went to `config.h` and it included only like 3 lines and the only #include was <linux/autoconf.h>.  When I went to autoconf.h it was also like 3 lines and had no #includes or any good information.  Does this mean my Compiler will never know what to do with any of the PATH_IPSEC_H's because my library doesn't have any information on them?

Comment: Interestingly, not all of my ipsec tools files that reference `PATH_IPSEC_H` contain the `#include "config.h"` line.